# How do i add pointers as properties in a class in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, properties

I'm pretty new to C# and was wondering if it was possible to add pointers as class properties. When I tried to do this, it gives me an error.

```cs
public class Example{
    public int *p;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? There is probably better solution than trying to use pointer on primitive in C#

Comment: @KarlosK. Oh, I'm trying to create a pointer to a contentManager in Monogame.

Comment: Try to mark your class as unsafe: public unsafe class Example

Comment: @ChrisMathew - If your `ContentManager` is a class then just store it as a member variable. It'll be a reference type and you can pass a reference to it by just copying the reference.

Comment: Pointers are usually very much frowned upon in c#. Chances are you will never need them. Do read up on managed memory !

Answer (score 1):

In C# you have the ability to hold the object reference instead of a pointer.
The int is a primitive type so it is not a reference,  in order to hole an int reference you shuld use the full Integer type.

Answer (score 0):

First - mark the field (variable) as unsafe (`public unsafe int *p`), second - turn on "allow unsafe code" in your project's properties, this should resolve it.
(As a tip for using pointers in c#, read about the `fixed` keyword!)